# can't login using session variable

Tags: php, mysql

i have this code, and i'm trying to create a session in order to get user's gallery id..

The problem is, if i use $_SESSION['username'] it works, but like this not... can you please check what's wrong with this?

Thanks!

```
mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass);
mysql_select_db($database);
$username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
$password = md5($_POST['password']);

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $table WHERE username = '$username' AND password = '$password'
");
while ($rows = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

if(mysql_num_rows($result))
{
$rows['gal_id']=$gal_id;
  session_start();
  $_SESSION['gal_id'] = htmlspecialchars($gal_id);
}
else
{
  // Invalid username/password
  echo '<p><strong>Error:</strong> Invalid username or password.</p>';
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you have *no* output at all above the `session_start();` as that will bork it.

Comment: yes sure.. i have nothing above session_start()

Comment: The question title says that using $_SESSION doesn't let you log in. The question content says that $_SESSION does work, but $_POST doesn't. Can you please clarify as to what the actual problem is?

Comment: Hey, well, the point is like this: if i use $_session[username] instead of session[gal_id] it works.. now there might be maybe an error with that, but i don't know what it is..

Comment: not an answer but md5 is considered to be not safe enough anymore to hash passwords. Also the mysql_* functions are deprecated in favor of mysqli_* or PDO

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change this:

```
$rows['gal_id']=$gal_id;
```

to

```
$gal_id=$rows['gal_id'];
```

EDIT: i dont think it need a furhter explanation

Comment: Hey, thanks, this made possible the login... can you please tell me, howcome, when i enter in the page then, i can' retrieve $_SESSION['gal_id'] , there's no output..

Comment: you have to start the session first to acces the session variables: `session_start();`

Answer (score 2):

`$rows['gal_id']=$gal_id;` You cannot set the value of a database row by doing this. Plus it is never further referenced.

`session_start();` This should be at the top of your page in most instances.

`$_SESSION['gal_id'] = htmlspecialchars($gal_id);` $gal_id is never set in your code to anything, it doesn't exist.

Comment: hey thanks.. so what i need is to get user's $gal_id that's why i was inserting it like that.. can you please suggest me how to do it?.. thanks!

Comment: Look at @Imre L's answer. However, for future use, you should look at the database with phpmyadmin or something of the like and see the name of the column. From there you can read the values similar to what he's saying.